# how to use existed Sequence number in C# Code to get auto increment in combination of two fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I have created a stored procedure as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Budget_Details]

@Budget_Type varchar(10)
,@Item_Category_Code varchar (20)
,@Item_Description varchar(500)
,@Configurations varchar(500)
,@Project varchar(100)
,@Budgeted_Qty numeric(9,2)
,@Reason_for_Budgeted_Cost numeric(9,2)
,@Total_Cost numeric(9,2)
,@Action varchar(10)
,@B_Number varchar(10)
AS
IF @Action='ADDNEW'
BEGIN
DECLARE @Budget_Number varchar(30)
DECLARE @Budget_FY_Code varchar(10)
DECLARE @seqNo AS integer
SELECT @seqNo=ISNULL(Budget_Num,0) FROM Seq_Master
SET @seqNo=@Budget_FY_Code+@seqNo+1
SET @Budget_Number=@seqNo

PRINT @Budget_Number

 INSERT Budget_Master
 (
  Budget_Number
 ,Budget_FY_Code
 ,Budget_Type
 ,Item_Category_Code
 ,Item_Description
 ,Configurations
 ,Project
 ,Budgeted_Qty
 ,Reason_for_Budgeted_Cost
 ,Total_Cost

 )

 VALUES
 (
  @Budget_Number
 ,@Budget_FY_Code
 ,@Budget_Type
 ,@Item_Category_Code
 ,@Item_Description
 ,@Configurations
 ,@Project
 ,@Budgeted_Qty
 ,@Reason_for_Budgeted_Cost
 ,@Total_Cost

 )
     UPDATE Seq_Master SET Budget_Num=@seqNo
END
ELSE IF @Action='EDIT'
BEGIN
    UPDATE Budget_Master

    SET 
       Budget_FY_Code=@Budget_FY_Code
      ,Budget_Type=@Budget_Type
      ,Item_Category_Code=@Item_Category_Code
      ,Item_Description=@Item_Description
      ,Configurations=@Configurations
      ,Project=@Project
      ,Budgeted_Qty=@Budgeted_Qty
      ,Reason_for_Budgeted_Cost=@Reason_for_Budgeted_Cost
      ,Total_Cost=@Total_Cost


    WHERE 
    Budget_Number = @B_Number                   
END
```

But its not working no seqNo is generating on execution and want to know that how to use this stored procedure in C# for web Form

Comment: Why have you tagged this C# and asp.net?  It seems related to sql more than anything?

Comment: What are you really asking? How to get the stored procedure to work, or how to execute it from C#?

Comment: You also need to do some casting here `SET @seqNo=@Budget_FY_Code+@seqNo+1` some of those variables are INTEGER and other VARCHAR

Comment: i have created a this stored procedure to retreive its values through a web page